# Flux in V/Hz to actual motor constant Ke?

Tags: brushless-dc-motor

I have some trouble to calculate the motor constant Ke in V/krpm from a known flux constant of the motor. The motor has a rated flux of 0.249V/Hz and 2 PP (pole pairs).

I already know, that Ke is 9.8V/krpm, but I do not see, how I can calculate this from the above rated flux?

The flux seems to be the electrical frequency and not the mechanical frequency of the motor and when I divide the flux by the number of PP, i come up with 0.1245V/Hz for the BEMF, but this seems to be false, since when I multiply this by 1000/60 i get only 2.075V/krpm, far from the specified value. I don't know, if the flux is in RMS or peak and also I do not know, if the flux is for line-neutral or line-line, which makes it even more difficult. What I know is, that the flux is directly used for BEMF compensation by multiplying it with the electrical angular speed in field oriented control.

Comment: https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Motor_constants  Where did your assumptions come from?

Comment: High Tony, which assumptions do you mean? The Ke is directly from the motor datasheet (and verified by measureing the BEMF) and the flux constant is evaluated by a TI motor controller and removes the Vq integrator load perfectly at any speed in the FOC controller. So these parameters fit perfectly for the motor, but i cannot find the physical relations between them.

Comment: Hi Hans, if you can link the datasheet and any other assumptions in the question, that might be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\$\phi=\dfrac{E_b}{K_\omega ~\omega}\$

\$ \phi  \$ = flux [V⋅s]
\$E_b=\$ back EMF [V]peak
\$K_v=\dfrac{1}K_e\$ RPM/Vpk ratio with no load
Sometimes \$K_e\$ is given in SI units volt–seconds per radian (V⋅s/rad)
[Other non-std units used in USA](http://biosystems.okstate.edu/Home/mstone/4353/downloads/Developement%20of%20Electromotive%20Force.pdf)

May have more time later...

Comment: Hi Tony, I could figure it out, it is indeed the conversion from RMS to peak and Line-Line to Line-Neutral.